# How pseudoantonyms or false antonyms in the English language can be identify?

Tags: antonyms, dictionaries

Pseudoantonyms give the misleading impression that they have opposite meanings because of the prefixes. Are not these misleading for the non native English speakers and learners? How can we identify them? When to use and how to use>

Comment: What do you mean, "justify"? Do you mean, give a satisfying reason they are in the language that would make it a good choice? Or do you mean "explain in a way that is understandable and easy to remember"?

Comment: What do you think a *pseudoantonym* is? Synonyms can have different meanings. Even the *same word* can have different meanings based on context. Are you saying that *nothing* in English should ever have more than a single meaning? If you have a question about antonyms specifically, please provide some examples.

Comment: Before reading Darael's answer, I was going to comment that you should write to the Académie anglaise and ask them to provide the justification you ask for, but I realise now that I have mislaid their address.

Comment: I am curious, can you name a language where these things don't exist?

Comment: By justifying i meant that they are confusing to the non native English speakers because usually after using prefix prior to a word it changes its meaning. Like inflammable and flammable, bone and debone, press and depress. They all have the same meaning and will be confusing. @NathanTuggy

Comment: I am not talking about same words having different meanings. I am talking about different words having same meanings. like inflammable and flammable, debone and bone, press and depress. @JasonBassford

Comment: @AqibCh Yes, but , however you express it, you seem to be arguing for a 1-1 correspondence between every word and every meaning: each word having a single meaning, and no other word having that meaning. As in another comment, such a thing doesn't exist in *any* language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

English is defined by usage.  There is no governing body that decides which words are acceptable parts of the language.  There are two ways a word can be "justified", therefore: either by its meaning being clear from context, or by its having a *history* of carrying that meaning.

Pseudoantonyms are in the second group.  They continue to exist in English because people continue to use them.  That is all.